# Creating module (standalone web application) using Grails to embed in PHP site

Tags: php, html, web-applications, embedding

I want to create a module (personal cabinet) to embed in an existing PHP site. I also want to create it using Grails, to use in other projects. Is there some pattern for creating standalone web applications to easily embed it in ready site?

Comment: What do you mean by "ready product" and "ready site"?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to embed one site within another without coding a site-specific interface is to use an iFrame.

As an alternative, I would suggest making a REST API for the embedded site and then each embedding site can use the API to integrate it.